# Target problems in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem. I have similar divs with the same classes. When I click on (toggle#1) with the `.comments-toggle` class I only need the div below `.toggle-container` to expand. As this code stands it will also trigger the `.toggle-container` div below (toggle#1) div to expand.

How do I click on toggle#1 and only the div below it with class `toggle-container` expand and not all divs with the class toggle-container?

*** EDITED HTML ****

I only need the JQUERY to be changed, please don't change the HTML as the solution.

I hope this make sense.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="comments-toggle">Toggle #1</div>
</div>

<div>
   <div class="comments-expanded-container toggle-container">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiumdod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div>
   <div class="comments-toggle">Toggle #2</div>
 </div>

<div>
   <div class="comments-expanded-container toggle-container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiumdod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.comments-expanded-container {
display: none;
}

.expand {
display: inline-block;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
 (function () {
     $('.comments-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
         $('.toggle-container').toggleClass('expand');
     })
})();
```

JS FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/Jakwakwa/c2ogevff/

*** EDITED HTML ****

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this).next()` inside the click listener to *target* the *next* `toggle-container` - see demo below:

```js
(function() {
  $('.comments-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).next('.toggle-container').toggleClass('expand');
  })
})();
```

```css
.comments-expanded-container {
  display: none;
}

.expand {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comments-toggle">Toggle #1</div>

<div class="comments-expanded-container toggle-container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiumdod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
</div>

<div class="comments-toggle">Toggle #2</div>

<div class="comments-expanded-container toggle-container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiumdod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I like the answer, but please check - I changed the Html in the question. Then your solution doesn't work anymore. Please see if you have another solution please - would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Jakwakwa use `$(this).parent().next().find('.toggle-container').toggleClass('expand')`